# Why Imx6q(Embedded Linux Device) ethernet communication is too slow?

Tags: linux, ethernet, tcp, udp, embedded-linux

I have tried several methods to test the ethernet communication of the Imx6 card.

1) When I ping in my computer from IMX6, the ping does not reach the IMX6. But when I ping to imx6 from the computer, it reaches. Test results is below.
[Test 1.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WtCIQ.jpg)

[Test 1.2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ud56n.png)

2) Tested with Iperf3. When the computer works as a client, it can receive data from imx6. However, when imx6 works as a client, imx6 cannot receive data. The bandwidth is too low. Test results is below.

[Test 2.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3sfy3.jpg)
[Test 2.2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MoVOo.jpg)

What are the causes of these problems?

What are your suggestions?

Regards

Emin

Test Environment

IMX6 Quad

U-Boot Versiyonu:  U-Boot 2015.04-TQMa6-20151002 (Sep 16 2016 - 14:58:59)

Kernel Versiyonu: 3.14.28-g5e30b53-dirty

Computer: ASUS R510V (Gigabit Ethernet)

Comment: Are these devices connected directly to each other or are you going through a switch? What are the network settings on each side?

Answer (score 1):

This is a combination of hardware limitation and poor software support. The i.mx6 is not able to reach line speed. NXP claims it is only 470Mbps (page 98 of http://cache.freescale.com/files/32bit/doc/errata/IMX6DQCE.pdf) but that they measured it to around 400 Mbps.

However, if you update to an upstream kernel, you should be able to reach around 600Mbps.

Answer (score 0):

Responding to your 2 points:

1. The ping times are fine (3ms or less). When you ping the PC from the imx6, the packet loss is probably due to firewall software on your pc.
2. I have experienced the same problem on an imx6 board.  You can resolve this with a (cheap) managed switch and turning 802.3x flow control on.  I have gotten just under 500mbps iperf3 receive speeds on the imx6 when flow control is on.